# If statements in for loops

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

how do I run only one of those if statements in a for loop? For example i have an input of 5...and i just want it to print five...but whenever i run this code, it will execute all if statement..please help me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Complete the code.
    int a;
    int b;

    cin >> a;

    for (a = 0; 0<a<10; a++)
        {
            if (a == 1)
                {
                    cout << "one";
            }
        if (a == 2)
                {
                    cout << "two";
            }
        if (a == 3)
                {
                    cout << "three";
            }
        if (a == 4)
                {
                    cout << "four";
            }
        if (a == 5)
                {
                    cout << "five";
            }
         if (a == 6)
                {
                    cout << "six";
            }
        if (a == 7)
                {
                    cout << "seven";
            }
         if (a == 8)
                {
                    cout << "eight";
            }
        if (a == 9)
                {
                    cout << "nine";
            }

        else if (a > 9 && a%2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "even";
        }
        else if (a > 9 && a&2 != 0)
            {
                cout << "odd";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? you are taking input in a, but again initialize a to 0 in the loop.

Comment: Remove `for` loop.

Comment: You need to find a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read up on conditional expressions. The one in the (unnecessary) `for` loop is not correct. And while reading the book, red about the `switch` statement. And arrays (you don't need a big chain of `if-else` or a `switch` statement).

Comment: `0<a<10` is not what you think neither.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the `for` loop. Your program accepts a value for `a` as an input, but then as soon as the loop begins, it resets the value of `a` to 0 (`for (a = 0;...`

Therefore it's looping 10 times, and on each loop `a` will have a different value, starting from 0 and ending at 9. This means that all of your `if` statements will get hit at some point in the execution, generally one on each of the loops round the `for`.

To get your expected behaviour " input of 5...and i just want it to print five", simply remove the `for` loop from your code.

Comment: Nice answer but don't forget to mention something about 0 < a < 10; feel free to take the points in my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba good point I hadn't noticed that. But if OP removes the loop it won't matter anyway. I think you've edited your answer since I posted mine...so yours is probably better now :-)

Answer (score -1):

**Your unnecessary `for` loop trashes the input value of `a` and loops forever!** (At least until you overflow your signed type `a`).

You are replacing `a` by using it as the counter in the `for` loop! If you only ever want *one* output, then drop the `for` loop completely. If your `for` loop were to remain then your expression `0 < a < 10` ought to be recast as `0 < a && a < 10` : formally `0 < a < 10` is evaluated as `(0 < a) < 10` which is either `true < 10` or `false < 10` which is *always* `true`.

Also consider refactoring your `if else` to set up explicitly mutually exclusive statements:

```
if (a == 1){
    cout << "one";
} else if (a == 2){
    cout << "two";    
/*and so on*/
} else {
    /*all other cases*/
}
```

Although in this case you might want to consider a `switch` block:

```
switch (a){
case 1:
    cout << "one";
    break; // to stop program control flowing into the next case
case 2:
    cout << "two";
    break;   
/*and so on*/ 
default:
    /*all other cases*/
}
```

Comment: What if a problem asked me to use for loop and ask to to output this :

For each integer  (so all numbers in that range):

If , 1<= n <=9 then print the English representation of it. That is "one" for 1, "two" for 2, and so on.
Else if  n>9 and it is even, then print "even".
Else if  n>9 and it is odd, then print "odd".

Answer (score -1):

```
if () {
} else if () {
}
```

Although,

```
switch() {
}
```

will be more efficient in your case.

**Update 1**

@Aleph0

Below is the solution

```
int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    switch (a) {
    case 1: cout << "one"; break;
    case 2: cout << "two"; break;
    case 3: cout << "three"; break;
    case 4: cout << "four"; break;
    case 5: cout << "five"; break;
    case 6: cout << "six"; break;
    case 7: cout << "seven"; break;
    case 8: cout << "eight"; break;
    case 9: cout << "nine"; break;
    default: cout << ((a & (1 << 31)) ? "negative" : (a & 1) ? "odd" : "even"); break;
    }
}
```

Question has been asked to do following

> i have an input of 5...and i just want it to print five

And, someone has correctly mentioned above, `for` loop is immaterial here.

Comment: Using switch() won't solve his problem. The loop is the real problem here.